# Eclipse function/plugin that finds corresponding junit class?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, eclipse-plugin

I've been searching high and low for an Eclipse feature that lets you right-click on a main source class and find the corresponding JUnit class(es), without me having to navigate through the test classes of my project. I am using Mylyn which helps reduce the clutter but it would be much easier if there was a feature that performs a find automagically.

I am following the Maven standard directory layout (`/src/main/java`, `/src/test/java`, etc.). And all of my test classes are named `*Test`. I'd imagine this can be feasibly implemented and probably already exists.

Is there a function or plugin in Eclipse that finds the corresponding JUnit test classes for a given main class?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [moreUnit](https://moreunit.github.io/MoreUnit-Eclipse/) plugin probably works for you.

Capabilities (from its site):

- Decorate classes which have a testcase.
- Mark methods in the editor which are under test.
- Jump to a testcase/testmethod in the editor via the menu or a shortcut.
- Rename classes/methods and moreUnit will rename the corresponding testcode too.
- Move classes and moreUnit will move the corresponding tests.
- Generate a testmethod stub for the method under cursor-position in the editor via the menu or a shortcut.

Comment: MoreUnit does not work any longer. During the installation, it cannot resolve the dependencies and just install the Light version that does not work properly.

Comment: @Ahmad Which MoreUnit version and which Eclipse version did you try to use together? According to the release notes (https://moreunit.github.io/MoreUnit-Eclipse/#releasenotes) the latest MoreUnit version requires Eclipse 2021-06. They have dropped support for earlier Eclipse releases.

Comment: I just tested with Eclipse 2021-09 and during the installation, it installed "MoreUnit For Java", and "MoreUnit Light" successfully. Therefore, our lovely MoreUnit is working fine and thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 6):

[This](http://fast-code.sourceforge.net/) plugin claims to be able to do this, as well as other stuff.

> An useful feature of this plugin is
>   the ability to jump between similar
>   class, e.g FooDAO to FooService,
>   FooService to FooAction, etc. To use
>   this feature, one needs to configure
>   this first. To configure, please go to
>   Windows -> Preferences ->Fast Code
>   Preferences -> Mapping Btween Similar
>   Classes. This is very similar to the
>   configuration for create similar
>   classes.

Answer (score 0):

As a partial answer to your question, there is no requirement that tests have a one to one correspondence with main classes, or any standard naming convention (even with maven). What you would want is a plugin that (for example based on a regex) matches source classNames to dest ClassNames, and then loads that. Such a plugin would allow you to do what you want (and also for other uses not related to junit), but I'm not aware of one.

Answer (score 0):

[Infinitest plugin](http://improvingworks.com/products/infinitest/eclipse/) runs your JUnits for those classes that you're changing, as you're changing them.  There is no need to right-click on the updated class to find the relevant JUnit class, and then to run it - it will get run automatically. Test errors (if any) will show up the same way as Eclipse shows syntax errors.