# Keyboard shortcut to switch between test and class in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, keyboard-shortcuts

Lets say you create a class `Foo` and a test `FooTest` ( standard JUnit test )
I want a keyboard shortcut to help quickly switch between the test and the class.

If that is not possible, something like TextMate's "Run focussed test" (<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>) might be of great help.

Comment: Great idea, it would be lovely to have a "Run test for class" context menu option and shortcut that used the usual test naming convention to find the associated test and run it. Looks like the Switcher plug-in is the closest thing yet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse function/plugin that finds corresponding junit class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399491/eclipse-function-plugin-that-finds-corresponding-junit-class)

Answer (score 46):

You can also use [moreunit](https://moreunit.github.io/MoreUnit-Eclipse/). I just installed it and it works fine, allowing to switch between source class and test class and also to run test class being in source class editor.

Comment: This plugin is AWESOME. So much so that I've upvoted you. I'd downvote my own answer if I could ;-)

Comment: Yeah, really nice!

Comment: With MoreUnit plugin: `Ctrl + J` or `Ctrl + U`

Comment: MoreUnit does not work any longer. During the installation, it cannot resolve the dependencies and just install the Light version that does not work properly.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a built in one, but there's a plug-in called "Switcher" which will allow you to do that, [here](http://code.google.com/p/switch-eclipse-plugin/)

Comment: I stopped doing Java dev a couple of years back, but following on from the other answer in this question, I stopped using Switcher and started using MoreUnit. It was awesome 2 years ago, and probably still is... :-)