# Eclipse TDD - How to join test and main source folders?

Tags: java, eclipse, tdd

When we are using Test driven devleopment, I always wonder how you easily reach or create the test class in Eclipse.

We have a maven setup with two source folders src/main/java and src/test/java

When I am opening a class in src/main/java looking for a bug, I want my test class side-by-side. But I have to search the tree for it. Of course you can use a search box like "Open Type", but it is still annoying and takes a lot of time. And when i go to the test my package explorer to the left shows the test package, so I can't see the other classes in the package and cannot easily open them.

Do I miss something to support my TDD workflow?
What is the best setup to have the test near by?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title of your question speaks about a bad practice: keeping production and test code together. This is a bad practice because there's the risk of deploying also tests in the final package(s).

But reading your request (if you are using JUnit) it looks like you want an Eclipse plugin such as MoreUnit which creates a shortcut and makes easier working with JUnit files by decorating source classes etc.
This plugin has also been cited in other SO responses such as:

[Eclipse function/plugin that finds corresponding junit class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399491/eclipse-function-plugin-that-finds-corresponding-junit-class)

Furthermore sometimes a production class is used in more than one test class you may also search for all occurrences of that source class and limit your result scope to test packages. If you don't use JUnit but instead you use another framework such as TestNG you will have to search for a different plugin because [MoreUnit](https://moreunit.github.io/MoreUnit-Eclipse/) is JUnit specific.

Hope it helps.

Comment: MoreUnit seems to be great. Thanks. But I think best practice would be to keep code, tests and documentation together. Just the tools my be not aware of this and I fully understand the test classpath vs production classpath problem. But as a developer it would be much better to keep things together which belongs together.